# Pure CSS infinite scroll doesn't work on mobile

Tags: css

I'm using CSS to automatically scroll a panoramic image. It works great on desktop, but not on mobile.

Here is my code:

```css
.panorama-new {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 560px;
}
.sliding-background {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/National_Stadium_panorama.jpg) repeat-x;
  height: 560px; /* original 560 */
  width: 16648px;
  animation: slide 60s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-8324px, 0, 0);
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="panorama-new">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested it on mobile and desktop, it works fine. What's the problem again?

Comment: @evilReiko the image doesn't show up at all on Chrome for Android. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I tested on iPhone/Chrome